# Собственный редактор блоков контента для админки

Tags: html, jquery, css

Хочу сделать редактирование блоков прямо с главной страницы админ панели, точнее когда пользователь(админ) нажимает на блок, то блок преобразовывается в редактор (как на скрине). И вот появляется проблема так как, когда я кликаю на один, то пропадают все и появляется один бланк. Как можно это сделать, что бы после клика изменялся только один блок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var autoCard = $(".auto__card");
var autoCardRed = $(".red_tekst")
$(autoCard).on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).fadeOut();
})
$("i").on("click", function(e) {
  $(autoCardRed).fadeIn();
  autoCardRed.val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="wrapper-block">
    <div class="auto__card">
      <div class="hover-block">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        <!-- Тут находится редактор -->
      </div>
      <div class="img-block">
        <img src="img/auto.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- /.img-block -->
      <div class="describe-block">
        <h5>Audi</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odio aliquam iste ab, delectus, ducimus qui iusto id culpa, eligendi ipsam animi cum dolorum neque commodi quia laborum tempore voluptatem. Repellat.</p>
        <p class="cena">Cena: 1500euro</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.describe-block -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.auto__card -->
    <div class="auto__card-red">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      <form action="admin.php" method="post">
        <div class="img-block">
          <input type="file" name="img">
        </div>
        <!-- /.img-block -->
        <div class="describe-block">
          <input class="red_tekst" type="text" placeholder="Wpisz nazwę samochodu" name="auto-nazwa">
          <textarea class="red_tekst" id="" cols="30" rows="10" style="resize: none" placeholder="Wpisz opis" name="opis"></textarea>
          <input class="red_tekst" type="text" placeholder="Wpisz cene w zł" name="cena">
          <input class="red_submit" type="submit" value="Zapisz">
        </div>
        <!-- /.describe-block -->
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.auto__card -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.wrapper-block -->
</div>
<!-- /.col-md-4 -->
```

Comment: Выложи код нескольких блоков

Comment: Подменяйте блок, тем, что нужно, сохраняйте в переменную результат прошлого блока, чтобы после нажатия на отмену, вернуть в прежнее состояние.